# Stop scrolling when div reaches fixed position on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stop scrolling when a DIV is in view and centered in the viewport as the user scrolls down the page.

When the page is stopped and the user scrolls I need the content of the DIV to scroll horizontally and then allow the user to continue scrolling.

```
    function pauseScroll() {
        //    $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
        disableScroll();

        console.log('trying to scroll Card: ' + selCard);

        setTimeout(pauseStop(), 500);
        slideCard(selCard);
        //   });
    }

    function pauseStop() {
        console.log('Pause Stop');
    }

    function unpauseScroll() {
        //    $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
        enableScroll();
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "enabled";
        document.getElementById("status").className = "enabled";
    }


    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
    var keys = {
        37: 1,
        38: 1,
        39: 1,
        40: 1
    };

    function preventDefault(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
    }

    function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
        if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    function disableScroll() {
        if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
            window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
        window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
        window.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
        document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
    }

    function enableScroll() {
        if (window.removeEventListener)
            window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null;
        window.onwheel = null;
        window.ontouchmove = null;
        document.onkeydown = null;
    }


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($("div").hasClass("cardstop")) {

            var top_of_element = $(".cardstop").offset().top;
            var bottom_of_element = $(".cardstop").offset().top + $(".cardstop").outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_screen = $(window).height()
            var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();
            var elHeight = bottom_of_element - top_of_element;
            var topSpace = ((($(window).height()) - elHeight) / 2);
            var scrollFix = top_of_screen + topSpace;

            //top_of_screen
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                // downscroll code
                console.log('Top of el: ' + top_of_element);
                console.log('TopScreen: ' + top_of_screen);
                console.log('Space: ' + topSpace);
                console.log('Bot of el: ' + bottom_of_element);
                console.log('BotScreen: ' + bottom_of_screen);;

                if (top_of_element < scrollFix) {

                    if (selCard = 1) {
                        console.log('One to Two');
                        pauseScroll();
                        selCard = 2;
                    } else if (selCard = 2) {
                        pauseScroll();
                        selCard = 1;
                    }
                    unpauseScroll();
                }
            } else {
                // upscroll code
                console.log('Scroll Up: ');

                if (selCard = 3) {
                    console.log('3 to 2');
                    pauseScroll();
                    selCard = 4;
                }

                if (selCard = 4) {
                    pauseScroll();
                    unpauseScroll();
                }
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;

            // if (bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) {

            // The element is visible, do something
        }

    });
```

The process is kind of working apart it's scrolling the card content too quickly and then moving on.

Any pointers on where I am going wrong would be great.

Regards

I've added a mockup on [jsfiddle]:https://jsfiddle.net/stato74/sjtp9wv3/2/

Comment: Your if's look kinda wrong `selCard = 1`. Should it not be `selCard == 1`?

Comment: Can you create a codepen or jsfiddle example? sometimes it is easier to share code and find problems then.

Comment: Are you sure you wanna do this? This scroll hijacking you are trying to achieve sounds cool but will piss people off since it deviates from well known and accepted pattern.

Comment: @Fabian .... I've put together a mockup on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I would admit you to use this JS tool: Waypoints 
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

If you prefer the hard way, then you can set "html, body{overflow-y=hidden}" and set your Div {overflow-y=scroll}

This will let you scroll the div instead of the whole page.
If I will find some time later, I can provide code for this (if needed)

Answer (score 0):

the maximum value of `scrollTop` is not `scrollHeight`, it's `scrollHeight` - `outerHeight`.

This will give you the correct value:

```
var elem = $("body");
var maxScrollTop = elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.outerHeight();
$(document).scroll(function(){
   if(e.target.scrollTop > maxScrollTop ){
     e.target.scrollTop = maxScrollTop ;
   }
});
```